# How to antialiase tiles when seeding a layer from an GeoTiff in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tiling

I have an GeoServer running that uses GeoWebCache.
As a data source I use a 1.5 GB big map for a layer.
The outcome of the tiling and scaling are very rough looking tiles.

Is there a way to antialiase the tiles, that they are more pleasant to look at?

Comment: Please, can you provide more details about your current setup? The problem could be, for instance, that you are generating GIF tiles; this image format only supports 256 different colors, which would be the cause of the tiles looking rough.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your response.
I found a solution for my problem.

In GeoServer under the point WMS you can activate antialiasing.
This was already checked but the raster rendering option was nearest neighbor.
I switched it to bilinear or bicubic and now the resulting tiles are nice and smooth looking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your original data image is high enough resolution to support nice looking tile output, you will likely want to modify your GeoWebCache configuration to request and serve higher quality images.

Take a look at this document that contains all of the potential configuration settings in GWC config XML file:  http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.2.1/_sources/configuration/xml/exhaustive.txt

I would suggest using the PNG24 image type.